# Disturbing regular level submanifold of a smooth function

Tags: differential-topology, singularity-theory

Let $a$ be a regular value of a smooth function on a closed manifold and $\{f=a\}$ a corresponding level submanifold. It is known that any such function can be approximated by a Morse function $g$. Assume that $a$ is also a regular value for function $g$. How different level submanifolds $\{f=a\}$ and $\{g=a\}$ can be?

Comment: How do you want to measure the difference of the two submanifolds? Hausdorff distance or something else?

Comment: Different in what sense? They are certainly diffeomorphic as submanifolds (assuming, of course, that $a$ remains a regular value all the way during the perturbation); actually, they are even diffeotopic. As long as you are speaking about regular values, you do not need to bother about other singularities.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, I am interested in a topological difference, homology or something. especcialy in a low-dimensional cases 1,2 and 3.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev, you mean that morsifications of a singular points can be provided in a sufficiently small neighbourhoods and this doesn't effect the regualr submanifolds?

Comment: Yes, of course. Morse functions constitute a dense subset. Although, of course, it is **not** true that there is a single Morsification not affecting **any** of the regular values: some will be affected (a singular point will break into several  Morse ones). But you can always keep one favorite regular value.

Comment: In other words, you can always find a Morsification whose critical values are in arbitrary small n/hoods of those of the original function. Outside of those n/hoods, nothing happens: everything is locally trivial.

Comment: A simple example: a smooth function on S^1xS^1 may have only 3 critical point, but if they are only 3 at least one is degenerate .

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev, thank you. So, if I want to study zero set of some smooth function which is regular I can proceed as follows: approximate it wih Morse and study its topology. Very usefull thing then.